# How to prove the boundedness of a weighted sum of projections?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T: \mathcal{D}(T)\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be defined by
$$Tx=\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}\lambda_{\gamma}E_{\gamma}x\; \text{ for every}\; x \in \mathcal{D}(T)$$

Where $\{E_{\gamma}\}_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ is an orthogonal family of projections and $\mathcal{H}$ a Hilbert space.

I want to prove the claim that

> T is bounded if and only if $\{\lambda_{\gamma}\}_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ is a bounded family of scalars, which happens if and only if $\mathcal{D}(T)=\mathcal{H}$. In this case $T \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ and $||T||=\sup_{\gamma \in \Gamma}|\lambda_{\gamma}|$.

My first idea was the following:
$$||Tx|| =\left|\left| \sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \lambda_{\gamma}E_{\gamma}x \right|\right|\leq \sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}|\lambda_{\gamma} |\, || E_{\gamma}||\, ||x|| 
= ||x|| \sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}|\lambda_{\gamma}|$$

where I have used that $||E_{\gamma}||=1$ since $E_{\gamma}$ is an orthogonal projection. But his would result in the claim that $T$ is bounded if $\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}|\lambda_{\gamma}|$ is finite which is a stronger assumption than bounded.

I appreciate any suggestions.

**Update**
Using the answer from LL I'm able to proof $||T||\leq \sup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}|\lambda_{\gamma}|$.
Assume $\mathcal{D}(T)=\mathcal{H}$ and take an arbitrary $x\in \mathcal{H}$ with then $\left\{E_{\gamma}x\right\}_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$ is a complete orthonormal set and therefore $||x||^{2}=\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}|\langle x, E_{\gamma}x \rangle|^{2}$ by Parseval's identity.
Using the Pythagorean theorem in the second step and Parseval's identity in the second to last step as well as $E_{\gamma}=E_{\gamma}^{\ast}$ and $E_{\gamma}E_{\gamma}=E_{\gamma}$ yields:

$$\begin{align}
\left|\left| Tx \right|\right|^{2}
=&
\left|\left| \sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \lambda_{\gamma}  E_{\gamma}x \right|\right|^{2}
=
\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} |\lambda_{\gamma}|^{2} \left|\left| E_{\gamma}x \right|\right|^{2}
=
\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} |\lambda_{\gamma}|^{2} \langle  E_{\gamma}x,E_{\gamma}x \rangle
=
\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} |\lambda_{\gamma}|^{2} \langle  x,E_{\gamma}x \rangle\\
\leq &
\sup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} |\lambda_{\gamma}|^{2}\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}  \langle  x,E_{\gamma}x \rangle
=
\sup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} |\lambda_{\gamma}|^{2} ||x||^{2}
\end{align}
$$

How do I proof that the inequality is strict, i.e. $||T||=\sup\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma}|\lambda_{\gamma}|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your assumption, $E_\gamma(x) = e_\gamma(x)\,\langle e_\gamma,x\rangle$ for an orthonormal family of vectors $e_\gamma$. If $\mathcal H$ is separable, then denoting by $x_\gamma := \langle e_\gamma,x\rangle$, by Parseval's identity
$$
\Big\|T(x)\Big\|^2 = \Big\|\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\lambda_\gamma\, x_\gamma\,e_\gamma\Big\|^2 = \sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma}|\lambda_\gamma|^2\, |x_\gamma|^2 \leq \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|^2 \sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |x_\gamma|^2,
$$
which implies
$$
\Big\|T(x)\Big\| \leq \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|\, \|x\|,
$$
and so $\|T\| \leq \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|$. To prove equality, just use the definition of the supremum to get that for any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\gamma_\varepsilon\in\Gamma$ such that $|\lambda_{\gamma_\varepsilon}| \geq \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|-\varepsilon$. In particular, since $T(e_\gamma) = \lambda_\gamma\,e_\gamma$, you deduce that
$$
\|T(e_{\gamma_\varepsilon})\| = |\lambda_{\gamma_\varepsilon}| \geq \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|-\varepsilon.
$$
Thus, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $\|T\| \geq \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|-\varepsilon$, hence $\|T\| \geq \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|$ and so $\|T\| = \sup_{\gamma\in\Gamma} |\lambda_\gamma|$.

Comment: Why do we need the separability of $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: To use Parseval's identity.

Comment: The version of Parseval's identity I know is based on complete orthonormal sets and thus does not require $\mathcal{H}$ do be separabel.